# How to use Open Library Cover API to fill sqlalchemy column?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I want to use the Open Library Cover API to take in the Author name and Book title and fill a column in my sqlalchemy database with the OLID so that I could use it to generate an image in my html files.
I am using Flask with WTForms to fill in the rest of the columns and I am very new to web dev so I am in way over my head. Any help or tips would be much appreciated.

Snippet of my models.py

```
class reviewedBook(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), primary_key=True)
    bookname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    author = db.Column(db.String(32))
    genre = db.Column(db.String(10))
    review = db.Column(db.Text)
    liked = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    cover = db.columnn(db.text)
```

The rest of the form

```
class reviewBook(FlaskForm):
    bookname = StringField('Name of the Book', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=1, max=50)])
    author = StringField('Name of the Author', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=2, max=32)])
    genre = SelectField('Book genre', choices=[('Romance', 'Romance'), ('Mystery', 'Mystery'), ('Fantasy', 'Fantasy'), ('Thrillers and Horror', 'Thrillers and Horror'), ('Young Adult', 'Young Adult')])
    review = TextAreaField('Review', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(max=200)])
    liked = BooleanField('Liked', default='unchecked')
```

A python program I did (have no idea how to actually feed through the results to other files and I am not very familiar with python)

```
import requests

def find_book_id(title, author):
    base_url = "https://openlibrary.org/search.json"
    
    # Constructing the query parameters
    params = {
        'title': title,
        'author': author
    }

    try:
        # Making the API request
        response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Check for HTTP errors

        # Parsing the JSON response
        data = response.json()

        # Extracting the book ID if available
        if 'docs' in data and data['docs']:
            book_id = data['docs'][0]['key'][7:]  # Extracting the key and removing the "/works/" prefix
            return book_id
        else:
            return "Book not found"

    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        return "Error"
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        return "Error"
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        return "Error"
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        return "Error"
```

Comment: I couldn't get what you are trying to achieve here. Can you explain how you're going to use Open Library Cover API  and WTforms step by step and where actually you need help?